# How to load diverse images with `tf.train.string_input_prodecer()` in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I get an image set full of images with different sizes and extensions. Most of their colorspaces is RGB while some got the extra alpha channel.

How can I convert them to 227*227*3 (3 means RGB) in tensorflow?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Image APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image)

In particular, what would be of interest to you is perhaps the following functions in the Cropping header:

```
tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad
tf.image.central_crop
tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box
tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box
tf.image.extract_glimpse
tf.image.crop_and_resize
```

As for the Alpha channel, it really depends on how you are reading in the images. If you are using `tf.image.decode_image`, you can perhaps try specifying `channels=3/4` (I'm not sure if this will break the code) but if it's like what you mentioned, some pictures have alpha and some don't, then you might want to use cv2 or PIL to entirely preprocess the images and crop them to 227x227x3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All the methods you mentioned indicate a crop, is there any method can shrink images without crop? Besides, could you please show me the code to read raw images and pre-process them to 227*227*3? I'm new to tensorflow, thanks for you help.